# Angular 2 can not include templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angular

i can not believe this, i can't load template for 2 hours. Shame on google this is very bad. I am learning this is very annoying.
So this is my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'mw-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent
```

project structure

```
--angular2-training
 --app
  --app.component.ts
```

tried to add
    moduleId: module.id, 
and changed  tsconfig.js
         "module": "commonjs",

tried with required(), nothing helps. Really sucks. Please help me

Comment: is the template at the same directory? you dont need the 'app', just './app.component.html'

Comment: what build system do you use? what tutorial do you follow?

Comment: Where's your HTML file located?

Comment: i have root folder angular2 and folder app in it. Html is in app folder where is my ts file

Comment: this is link to tutorial

Comment: https://github.com/LyndaExerciseFiles/angular2-essential-training/tree/master/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use WebPack try this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'about',
    template: require('./about.component.html'),
    styles: [String(require('./about.component.scss'))]
})
```

Double check the path of your template .. and try to put ./ before even if the template is in the same directory of your ts file

Comment: can you expain me what is webPack i downloaded some lynda tutorial over git

Comment: webpack is tool like Gulp to build your app (minified ..transpile es6 to es5 ..and then resolve dependencies)  https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: try with the ./ in the front of your url

Comment: used npm, is that?

Comment: i am php developer not familiar with angular, will try

Comment: :-) ..let me know if it works .. hope it help you .. or put in the correct way :-)

Comment: @VladimirŠtus, give a link to the tutorial

Comment: @VladimirŠtus, ok, let me see. _The repository has a branch for each video starting point._ Which branch are you modifying?

Comment: here it is https://github.com/LyndaExerciseFiles/angular2-essential-training/tree/02_06b/app

Comment: @VladimirŠtus, okay, everything works for me. What changes did you make?

Comment: tnx dude my bad  typed class export instead export class

Comment: very happy to helped you